# В чем разница между SerializedName и именем переменной?

Tags: java, android

Объясните в чем разница между

```
@SerializedName("name")
public String str;`  

// и   

public String str
```

Доступ к переменной я и так и так могу получить. Зачем тогда `SerializedName` нужен?

Comment: name - это имя поля в json. str - в java. анотация их связывает

Comment: Разница лишь в том, что при сериализации этого класса с помощью библиотеки `GSON` в json-строку  это поле будет записано с именем из аннотации, а при десериализации значение этого поля будет прочитано по этому самому имени. Без `GSON` и использования его де/сериализации эта аннотация не имеет никакого смысла и на работу java-кода никак не влияет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью аннотации [SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) из `Gson` можно указывать имя сериализуемого/десериализуемого поля при парсинге Json или при переводе объекта в Json.

Например у вас есть ваш класс:

```
class MyString {
   @SerializedName("mystring") public String str; 
}
```

и Json вида `{"str":"some text"}`, тогда при десериализации этого Json ваше поле `str` будет `null`, потому что вы явно указали, что при десериализации в `str` должно писаться значение из поля json `mystring`. То есть если вы хотите, чтобы json правильно десериализовался, нужно передавать такой Json в этом случае: `{"mystring":"some text"}`

При отсутствии аннотации `SerializedName` поле будет десериализовываться на основе имени поля в классе, с поправкой на [FieldNamingPolicy](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/FieldNamingPolicy.html), которую вы указали при создании объекта `Gson` (либо `FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY` - значение по умолчанию).

Comment: А зачем нужен seriliazedName если `public String str` и без аннотации прекрасно работает. тоесть может через точку хранить данные и получать данные.

Comment: @EraNewGames, `public` и `SerializedName` это конструкции из совершенно разных областей, `public` - это модификатор видимости, `SerializedName` - это аннотация для работы с Json. Если вы не сериализуете/десериализуете объекты этого класса в Json, то эта аннотация вам не нужна. Я не очень понимаю что вы хотите узнать.

Answer (score 4):

Java class example,

```
public class Person {

            @SerializedName("name")
            private String personName;

            @SerializedName("bd")
            private String birthDate;

        }
```

Этот класс имеет два поля, они аннотируются аннотацией **@SerializedName**. Параметр (значение) этой аннотации - это имя, которое будет использоваться при сериализации и десериализации объектов. Например, поле Java **personName** представляется как **name** в JSON.

JSON Example,

```
{
    "name":"chintan",
    "bd":"01-01-1990"
}
```